# How do i redirect the page after first time added to cart Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to redirect to another page after first time user add an item to the cart, but It's not work in functions.php

```
//count cart size
function count_woocommerce_cart() {
    return sizeof( $woocommerce->cart );
}

if (count_woocommerce_cart() == 1){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
}
```

How do i redirect the page after first time added to cart?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I had time to test it, and this final code should work for the following conditions:

1. You have only added one of the item to your cart
2. This will also work if you delete the item and add one item again.

Based on your script, it looks like that's what you intended, but let me know if not.

```
//count cart size
function count_woocommerce_cart($woocommerce) {
    return $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
}

add_filter( 'add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
  global $woocommerce;
  if (count_woocommerce_cart($woocommerce) == 1){
    return "/sample-page/"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. add_to_cart_redirect nor woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect works

Comment: because it will run to the view cart page

Comment: What happens if you put my code exactly as is in your functions.php file, except you add `return "/";` as the first line of `custom_add_to_cart_redirect` ?  (In theory, this should make it redirect to your home page.  Also, what version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: woocommerce 2.38. It doesn't effect the code at all. I'm not sure why

Comment: That's strange; it should.  I tested it on my installation.  Are you using a child theme?

Comment: I copy whole folder of template into my_theme/woocommerce folder. I will get you the link  of my website soon

Comment: I'm not even able to visit the single product page, never mind add it to the cart.  Is that normal, or are you running other tests right now?

Comment: oh, I set everything on the post page, no individual page for those. Even thought, when im trying it on another machine with no customization woo and wp, it is still not do the direction neither, quite odd

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment.  What other plugins do you have (especially as pertain to WooCommerce)?

Comment: only woocommerce and pullout plugin for the widget. That's all i have

Comment: Hmm..  Pullout shouldn't cause a problem with WooCommerce.  What's your theme?

Comment: I sent you an email.  As I suggested there, you should probably delete your comment now with your address.